# Can I manage a git credential from Github? Does it expires after a time without usage?

Tags: github, git-credential-manager

Is there any way I could check and manage my credentials to push/pull repositories in github website? Because there's a computer from the company I work which I have no access anymore, and I would like to remove the credential to push/pull repositories from my github account.

Can I manage that in github website platform? I believe I have right now only two credentials.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you use ssh or a personal access token?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/token-expiration-and-revocation

Comment: If you were using your account username/password to push (not even sure if github still allows this) then you probably need to change your password. All other forms of authentication can be revoked through your account settings.

Comment: @apokryfos Github no longer allows to push using web password. The only supported authentication methods for push are PATs and SSH keys.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I used access token.